# AWS CloudFormation Cognito Identity Provider (SAML)

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

I am trying to create a Cognito Identity Provider with the help of documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpoolidentityprovider.html. Here is a sample of the snippet where the FederationMetadata.xml is in the same folder as the CF template definition.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Identity Provider

Resources: 
  CognitoUserPoolAIdProvider:
    Type: "AWS::Cognito::UserPoolIdentityProvider"
    Properties:
      AttributeMapping:
        email: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress
      IdpIdentifiers: []
      ProviderDetails:
        IDPSignout: 'false'
        MetadataFile: './FederationMetadata.xml'
        SLORedirectBindingURI: https://<IP of ADFS>/adfs/ls/
        SSORedirectBindingURI: https://<IP of ADFS>/adfs/ls/
      ProviderName: MyIdProvider
      ProviderType: SAML
      UserPoolId: us_abcdef123
```

Upon trying to run, I get the error with

```
Invalid XML (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException; Request ID: c047641b-7c69-4944-b4e4-e110cf8c2605)
```

I see that the file contents are not provided during run-time:

```
{
    "ProviderName": "MyIdProvider",
    "UserPoolId": "us_abcdef123",
    "AttributeMapping": {
        "email": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress"
    },
    "ProviderDetails": {
        "MetadataFile": "./FederationMetadata.xml",
        "SSORedirectBindingURI": "https://<IP>/adfs/ls/",
        "IDPSignout": "false",
        "SLORedirectBindingURI": "https://<IP>/adfs/ls/"
    },
    "ProviderType": "SAML",
    "IdpIdentifiers": []
}
```

Question: How should I be referring to the FederationMetadata.xml file within the CF Template? In addition, pasting the contents of the XML file work fine, but I want to externalize the metadata contents into a file entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input of MetadataFile is the contents of the XML, not the file path. So you have some alternative choices:

1. Switch to use `MetadataURL` that accept a public URL to meta data file
2. or If you use AWS CLI to CFN deployment, you can use MetadataFile as CFN as parameter and pass the XML contents to deploy script, for example:

```
    metadata=$(cat FederationMetadata.xml)

    aws cloudformation deploy --stack-name YOUR_STACK --parameter-overrides MetadataFile="${metadata}"
```

Your CFN would be used: `MetadataFile: Ref !MetadataFile`

Comment: I was aware of MetadataURL property, but the second option works perfect for me.